# What privileges are needed to re-open an "on hold" question?

Tags: support, privileges

I have been trying to figure out how to mark an "on hold" question to be re-opened.

https://superuser.com/questions/871465/build-a-modern-pc-using-a-dell-dimension-4300-case

This question was put on hold as too broad, but I believe the author has shown quite a bit of effort, and I would like to mark the question to be re-opened.

But I can't figure out how. Do I not have the necessary privileges yet? Or am I just not using the right buttons?

Comment: I believe [reopen](http://superuser.com/questions/871465/build-a-modern-pc-using-a-dell-dimension-4300-case#) opens up 2000 reputation.  Of course the question also has 4 questions.

Comment: I tend to suggest stuff like this get asked in chat. There's just so much stuff that's unique to the situation that its very broad.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback guys, much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're ever uncertain about privileges, just [visit the privileges list in the help center](https://superuser.com/help/privileges). It will show you each privilege level and whether you have reached it.

As you can see from there, it requires 3000 reputation points to vote to close/reopen questions.

If you have <3k rep and want a question to be reopened, you can leave a custom moderator flag on the question. However, don't abuse this – for example, repeatedly flagging the same question.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I had already looked at the privilege page on my profile but it wasn't completely clear to me. I'll mark your answer and go on a quest for more rep so I can reach 3k!